# How do I use the JSONP datatype with Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js

How do I set up Ember Data to use the JSONP datatype when making its ajax calls? I am going to be using Ember with Phonegap and need to make cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your own adapter which uses jsonp, you can do just that by extending a current one, have a look.

```
App.MyAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({})
```

Then you need to implement the find method among others, to use jsonp, could be something like this

```
App.MyAdapter= DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  find: function(store, type, id) {
     var item;
     $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.domain/someModel',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(response){
        item = App.someModel.create(order))
      }
    });
    return item;
  },
```

This is not tested, but it should give you the idea of how i can be done. :)

Comment: This worked, since thankfully there is only one method in Ember-Data that requires defining the dataType.

Comment: One other thing to note however, which I figured out while doing this, is that Phonegap doesn't require using JSONP, just setting domain accessibility in the config.xml.

Answer (score 7):

It's much easier to override the private `ajaxOptions` function instead of using `jQuery`. Ember's pipeline includes the removal of the jQuery dependency anyways. So do this instead:

`adapters/application.js`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    ajaxOptions: function(url, type, options) {
        var hash = this._super(url, type, options);
        hash.dataType = "jsonp";
        return hash;
    }
});
```

It would be create if the Ember core team could expose a public method to officially support this (instead of hacking a private api).

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/1.0.0-beta.15/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L915

Comment: This is definitely the better answer