# handling a jsonp callback in an ember component

Tags: ember.js, callback, ember-data, jsonp, jquery-callback

I have a jsonp request to retrieve feature information via geoserver, the call looks something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  _selectParcel: function() {

    function handleJson(data){
      console.log(data);
    }

    $.ajax('url/geoserver/wms', {
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
      service: 'WFS',
      version: '1.1.0',
      request: 'GetFeature',
      typeName: 'name_here',
      maxFeatures: 10000,
      outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
      srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
      bbox: '-73.68229866027832, 40.97056664236637, -73.68229866027832, 40.97056664236637, EPSG:4326'
    },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonpCallback: 'callback:handleJson',
      jsonp: 'format_options'
    });

  }
});
```

The problem that I run into is dealing with the callback scope - in this case, handleJson()

I have also tried

```
.then(function(){});
```

after the ajax call but with no luck.

_selectParcel is going to be called frequently based on mouse movement.

How should the jsonp callback be handled within the Ember component?

I've seen this [using ember data with jsonp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654532/how-do-i-use-the-jsonp-datatype-with-ember-data) but im not sure how to interact with an adapter from the component.

Console errors look like : "Uncaught ReferenceError: handleJson is not defined" the way its written above - and "Uncaught ReferenceError: parseResponse is not defined" when using callback=? and a ".then(function(){})" promise

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: yeah, its "Uncaught ReferenceError: handleJson is not defined" the way its written above - and "Uncaught ReferenceError: parseResponse is not defined" when using callback=? and a ".then(function(){})" promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there are really 2 pieces here.

1. should ember components request data
2. how are geoserver jsonp requests handled

For the first one I found this write up helpful [Should Components Load Data](http://emberigniter.com/should-components-load-data/)

For the second, this bit where the format_options and the jsonpCallback keys match did the trick. Thank you to [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76638/geoserver-2-4-1-how-to-use-jsonp-in-a-wfs-request)

```
$.ajax('url/geoserver/wms', {
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      service: 'WFS',
      version: '1.1.0',
      request: 'GetFeature',
      typeName: 'name_here',
      maxFeatures: 10000,
      outputFormat: 'text/javascript',
      srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
      bbox: '-73.68229866027832, 40.97056664236637, -73.68229866027832, 40.97056664236637, EPSG:4326',
      format_options: 'callback:getJson'
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'getJson'
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
  jsonpCallback: 'callback:handleJson'
```

to

```
  jsonpCallback: 'handleJson'
```

Comment: You're right! The jsonpCallback had to be changed, and I also had to change the format_options key to match. Thanks =)